# Unable to fetch API data using getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch a users name from the JSON placeholder API and just simply display it but it seems to be coming back as undefined and not sure why. Any help would be great!

```
function GetServer({ data }) {

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
  const data = await res.json()

  return { props: { data } }
}

export default GetServer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, the above code is not inside a page. You have to be inside a page file.

> getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props